# solr index comma separated values

Tags: solr

I'm working with Solr 4.4  and have a delimited field that I would like split into individual values.

### sample value

"Internal", "B2B","Channel"

### Schema.xml

```
<field name="Audience" type="commaDelimited" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="true" omitPositions="true" omitTermFreqAndPositions="true" />



<fieldType name="commaDelimited" class="solr.TextField">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="," />

      </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

When i query

Audience:B2B :Getting result

Audience:b2b :Not Getting result

i know we can use

```
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
```

but the problem is for the facetfield
Audience,i get the result in lowercase like

> b2b,channel,internal

Any inputs please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use multiple fields. One with the lowercase filter attached for searching, and one without for indexing. Use a `<copyField>` instruction to copy all content that's heading into the `Audience` field into a `Audience_facet` field (or whatever you want to name it).

```
<copyField source="Audience" dest="Audience_facet" />
```